# Cant access data in for loop

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

i have a very straight forward question, but i just cant simply solve it, even though in other file, everything is working. I just simply cant access the data which i want to push into array. Im adding a picture which explains everything.

[image]

when i do 'console.log(data)' i get an wanted result as well. But once its in for loop, its undefined.

**EDIT**
Adding another picture of what result i get after i do:

console.log(data) right before the FOR loop.
[image: 2nd image]

Whats weird, that in another .html file, i do exact same with the SAME JSON Structure data, and everything works..

Comment: Are you sure there are 1000 elements in the array?

Comment: It doesnt matter, I know that there is 40 elements and if i will do 40, its same

Comment: Then you want to do `y <= 39` or `y < 40` or you will access the first out of bounds element.  You should really use `length` though.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that `data` actually starts its entries at 0.  The fact you're logging `data[1].Text` seems to imply they might start at 1 for some odd reason.  This isn't typical for JavaScript, but also not impossible since we don't know what `data` contains.

Try running this code—if the output you get is `undefined` you may be starting at the wrong index too.

```js
console.log(data[0]); // undefined?
```

Comment: I get data, as expected. you can check my edited question with more info

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over that array 1001 times. You probably can't guarantee that the same amount of items is returned. A soon as you try to get an index from the array that simply doesn't exist, it will try to access `Text` of an item that doesn't exist.

```
for (let y = 0; y < data.length; y++){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Still the same. I was doing 
for (let y = 0; y < data.Count; y++){
Which is in data as well, then i get no errors, but its not working at all after that.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your data you are receiving from the backend. Did you inspect the returned data in the network tab?

Comment: Edited the question, check what i get in the network tab

Comment: Then there is something else wrong because the code shouldn't be

Comment: https://xnia140ixg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Stage1/currencies/sentiment

This is the link im using axios to get data from. What else can be wrong? :/ Simple function :(